# Twitter bootstrap full width panels being trimmed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a fixed width page using bootstrap and I noticed when testing it on iPhone the full width header and footer background were clipped to 70% of the width.

It's Business marketing type site, frequented by people looking for a supplier, normally from their office PC so the responsive aspect was not a requirement but I digress.

### Back to the problem

Viewing on a full size screen it looks as it should but if you scroll smaller than the limits of the container class (940px in this case) and then scroll back a little you can see the background has trimmed.

I have been tinkering with it for a while to the point where I have stripped everything out and just put in a simple bunch of nested divs to test and make sure the issue is not some rouge tag but it still does exactly the same thing.

I think the issue is related to items that are not wrapped in the class of container but if I need a full width panel and 940px fixed content I am not sure how I am going to achieve it with bootstrap.

```
// This Fails
<body>
    <header class="fullwidth">
        <div class="container">
            <p>The content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

// This is fine but not full width
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <p>The content</p>
    </header>
</body>
```

I have not adulterated bootstrap if I remove it or my styles together and restyle the body manually it goes away. But it seems to be a cumulative issue...

Anyone come across this before?

I don't really want to have to strip bootstrap out if possible.

As requested I have appended the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/NcZFz/3/

If you notice in jsfiddle whatever size your viewport is the header will fill it, but the view port only. And if you are using a MAc and have a magic mouse (or whatever) you can scroll right in that view port to see white. But this is supposed to be edge to edge so there should be no white.

Comment: Are you including the responsive css file ? or any combined version ? If you could reproduce the bug using [some jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/NcZFz/) and maybe fixing the closing `</header>` of the 1st example.

Comment: I'll put it on only I'll have to embed the bootstrap in its entirety

Comment: The responsive part of bootstrap adds margins, so you need to set a negative margin for full width items.  I saw how bootstrap did it on there own page with the @media (max-width: 480px) css tags in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a margin on the `<ul id="menu-primary-navigation">`

```css
#menu-primary-navigation { margin-left: 0; }
```

And you should also put `.clearfix` on the same element (because children are floating)

```html
<ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="clearfix">
```

Check this [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/NcZFz/2/).

All the above fixes could be avoided if you used the `.navbar .nav` classes (and associates) : read [the doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

Comment: That's my bad, I rushed to get some code in to jsfiddle and omitted some other styles. Even still after you modification the header is still only assuming the size of the viewport. and you are able to scroll to the right of it. 

In normal circumstances the header background should be visible in that area but it isn't?

Comment: @ChrisRymer I still don't see what you mean. The header background IS visible (#332 thing), and no scrolling involved. Check the [fullscreen version](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NcZFz/3/show/)

Comment: Try this: Close the window by half then scroll horizontally to the left to reveal the right hand side of the page. You will see the header has stopped when it should be full width. It is adjusting to what ever size the viewport is.

Comment: @ChrisRymer This is the expected behavior in non-responsive layout. You can set the background to the container, or set an `overflow: hidden` on the header (or the body), or use the responsive design.

Comment: Holy cr*p, how come I have never noticed this before!

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is not retaining the full width for me. I can't believe I wasted so much time trying to work out what was wrong. Know I know about it I can see it everywhere!

Comment: @ChrisRymer playing with `overflow` is just a quick fix to hide the *design inconsistency* in small resolutions, since you don't really support small resolutions without a real fix.

Comment: I was creating the site with another guy and we both and we decided to try out bootstrap (which is great) but didn't realise the viewport meta tag makes mobile devices retain the full size view. So when you double tapped the body had already assumed the screen width highlighting the problem. The fact I didn't realise this behaviour in the body annoys me a little. But I just commented the viewport meta out for now until I add some responsive elements. Thanks for the pointers!